# R histogram group by interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning R right now and I need to figure out a way for instance to take a data frame like this

```
m b
1 5
2 9
3 14
4 5
5 7
6 9
```

to this

```
m b length
1 5 short
2 9 short
3 14 medium
4 5 medium
5 7 long
6 9 long
```

where the criteria for the length column is based on the number in the m column (1-2 short, 3-4 medium, 5-6 long)

The reason I want to do it so I can use ggplot histograms and group by length and create a dodged histogram

Actually if I can skip creating a new column it would be better.  But I can't see how to do it in ggplot

For instance I want to do something like `ggplot(df,aes(b,group=length,fill=length))+geom_histogram(position="dodge",binwidth=2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `cut`

```
cut(df$m, breaks = c(0,2.5,4.5,Inf), labels=c('short', 'medium', 'long'))
[1] short  short  medium medium long   long  
Levels: short medium long
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use `mutate` and `between` from `dplyr` to add another column as `length`.

The steps could be:

```
library(dplyr)
# data
df <- read.table(text = "m b
1 5
2 9
3 14
4 5
5 7
6 9", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- df %>% mutate(length = ifelse(between(m,1,2), "short",
                             ifelse(between(m,3,4),"medium","long")))

#Result

#  m  b length
#1 1  5  short
#2 2  9  short
#3 3 14 medium
#4 4  5 medium
#5 5  7   long
#6 6  9   lon
```

The addition of new column as `length` can be avoided. Just replace `length` as `factor(ceiling(m/2))` in `ggplot` calls.

Hence the call will be:

```
  ggplot(df,aes(b,group=factor(ceiling(m/2)),
  fill=factor(ceiling(m/2), labels = c("Short","Medium", "Long"))))+
  geom_histogram(position="dodge",binwidth=2)+
  labs(fill = "Length")
```

But then you have to manually name `legend`.

[image]

Comment: You might also use `case_when` if there were more categories.